# Does every nonnegative $o_p(1)$ sequence bound some $o(1)$ sequence in probability?

Tags: probability, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a nonnegative sequence of random variables that converges to zero in probability, i.e. $a_n\rightarrow_p 0$. Is it true that we can always find a positive sequence of constants $\{\varepsilon_n\}$ such that $\Pr(a_n\ge \varepsilon_n)\rightarrow 0$, and $\varepsilon_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 0):

This follows directly from the definition of convergence in probability, I think.

$a_n \overset{P}{\rightarrow} 0$ if and only if $\forall \epsilon >0$ $P[|a_n| > \epsilon] \rightarrow 0$.

This is true for all $\epsilon$, so just pick an $\epsilon$, and set $\epsilon_n = \epsilon$ for all $n$.

You have to take into account the absolute value, but just expanding it into:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P[|a_n| > \epsilon] & = P[a_n>\epsilon \cup a_n < -\epsilon]\\
& = P[a_n>\epsilon ] + P[a_n<-\epsilon]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Because all probabilities are nonnegative $P[|a_n| > \epsilon]\rightarrow 0$ implies that $P[a_n>\epsilon ] \rightarrow 0$. The previous argument then works in the same way without the absolute value.

Comment: Sorry I missed the most important part of the question: I need $\epsilon_n$ to converge to zero also. Thanks for the reply anyways!